# How to 301 all posts

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I am currently using domain/%postname%/ but I am looking to change it to domain/folder/%postname%/ - I unsure how to 301 all posts.

If I was to use something like Redirect 301 /$ domain/folder/$ I am thinking this would probably also redirect all pages, archives etc to the same structure, which I do not want. How can I do this for posts only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) Plugin automatically adds a 301 redirection when a post url changes.
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960948/wordpress-how-to-redirect-old-links-after-changing-permalink-structure) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Already tried it. Doesn't seem to work. :/

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.